# Java ApachePDFBox 2 visual signatures on the same page, the second signature is not visible

Tags: java, pdfbox, signature

I use PDFBox 3.0.0 RC1 and I can successfully produce the first visual signature but the second visual signature is not displayed on the page.

Both signatures are validated by Acobat Reader, in the signatures panel but only the first signature has a corresponding visual representation on the page. So this is the problem, the second signature has no visual representation even if I've set the coordinates and an image.

The locations of the signatures on the page are different.
However, if I place the second signature on another page then both signatures are visible.

I tested this behaviour using the code from here: https://github.com/Luis-3M/SignPDF/blob/master/CreateVisibleSignature.java

I only made small modifications to use Windows Store and I replaced "PDDocument.load" with "Loader.loadPDF" as the new version of PDFBox has changed the way PDF is loaded.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5243

Comment: Now fixed in snapshot https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

Answer (score 1):

I switched from PDFBox3.0.0 RC1 to 2.0.24 and is fine now, both signatures are visible.